# Continental nations word search

Tags: geography, anagram, word-search

This square is composed of nations, all in the same continent, written either horizontally or vertically. There is no overlap, each letter belongs to exactly one nation. However, the country names are anagrammed. Please find the continent and all the nations.

```
B C R O O M O C
I U N D U S A A
M A R E I G N R
I E B I A L Y A 
N G A N A H G D  
A N T Y P E G W 
A I I E B N N N
A A T O W N S B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's

> Africa

Countries:

> - Morocco (row 1, from column 2)
>  - Botswana (row 8)
>  - Ghana (row 5, from column 3)
>  - Rwanda (column 8, from row 2)
>  - Niger (row 3, from column 3)
>  - Egypt (row 6, from column 3)
>  - Benin (row 7, from column 3)
>  - Libya (row 4, from column 3)
>  - Sudan (row 2, from column 3)
>  - Guinea (column 2, from row 2)
>  - Namibia (column 1, from row 1)

Comment: Beat me to it :P

Comment: You made a nice picture :)

Answer (score 7):

The countries are from

> Africa

Here's the grid:

> [image]

And here's a list of countries (roughly top to bottom):

> MOROCCO, NAMIBIA, GUINEA, RWANDA, SUDAN, NIGER, LIBYA, GHANA, EGYPT, BENIN and BOTSWANA