# Anagrid (word search with anagrams)

Tags: knowledge, anagram, word-search

I have to give Tom [the opportunity for a rematch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97295/a-derivative-word-search#comment276206_97295), so here's my attempt at an Anagrid ([here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97282/11110) is the first puzzle in the series). The rules:

This square is composed of elements, all in the same set, written either horizontally or vertically. There is no overlap, each letter belongs to exactly one word. However, the letters of the words have been reordered. Please find the words, and which one is obviously missing from the set.

```
c c o s e t e d
i m a l e n a s
n s s k u d t t
e i k a s s a y
k t m e e n t k
i u o a m e a l
m d m a n g e r
i c l a m a n a
```

Comment: Does this wordsearch allow words written backwards/upwards as well as forwards/downwards? **;-)**

Comment: The letters have been reordered, I can't tell whether they have been written backwards or not :)

Comment: 'Twas a joke comment.

Comment: Now I'm thinking of a [tag:grid-deduction] variant for this series...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are words for

> GERMAN in different languages

The words are

> Tedesco - Italian - R1C2
>  German - English - R7C3
>  Tysk - Danish/Norwegian/Sweden - C8R2
>  Almanca - Turkish - R8C3
>  Német - Hungarian - R5C3
>  Alemán - Spanish - R2C2
>  Saksa - Finnish  - R4C3
>  Alemao - Portuguese - R6C3
>  Niemi(e)cki - Polish - R1C1?
>  Duits - Dutch - R3C2
>  Dútsk - West Frisian - R3C3
>
>  I guess the obviously missing one is Deutsch.

Comment: You're missing one in the third row...

Comment: I hadn't noticed I'd missed, but after you noted still took a long time to find an anagram - and I don't know the subject!

Comment: The question also asks for the obviously missing one.

Comment: @LannyStrack, thanks for this, I hadn't read to the end of the question. Took a try.

Comment: Yes, the final answer is now correct. And indeed I made a typo in the longest one, sorry for that.

Comment: Daaaamn. That explains why I was having trouble finding English words in many places. Great job, Tom and @Glorfindel.